# Cómo descargar carpetas con archivos ".txt" desde una página web?

Tags: html, web, txt, descarga

Mi pregunta puede ser quizá una tontería pero mira, yo estoy desesperado... llevo buscando cómo hacerlo horas y horas y estoy seguro de que se puede hacer porque de otra forma me puedo morir descargando archivos

Veréis, tengo que descargar unos archivos ".txt" de una página de la NASA que contienen medidas de ozono para hacer un TFG. El caso es que yo no tengo ni idea de programación ni de informática apenas, así que no se me ocurre una mejor forma para descargar los archivos que uno a uno. La página es esta:

https://ozonewatch.gsfc.nasa.gov/data/omps/

Ahí están las carpetas (los directorios Y2020/, Y2019/, etc) con los datos del ozono (en archivos .txt) repartidos por años. La página me deja descargar, dentro de las carpetas, los archivos .txt UNO A UNO, sin problema.
Claro, que si tengo que descargar 365 datos a mano, por cada año de datos de ozono que quiera estudiar pues me puedo jubilar casi para cuando quiera analizar algo.

Alguien sabría explicarme cómo puedo descargar las carpetas Y2020, Y2019, etc; directamente con todos los archivos .txt???

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te recomiendo que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender cómo funcionamos, de lo contrario me temo que tu pregunta no será bien recibida y acabará cerrada.

Answer (score 0):

ya lo resolví, lo dejo por si a alguien le sirve:

Resulta que hay un programa llamado "wget", que originalmente era de Linux pero tiene su versión para Windows. Solo hay que descargarlo (en 32 o en 64 bits) y ejecutarlo en la consola de comandos, añadiendo el enlace a la página web donde estén los archivos que quieres descargar, y automáticamente se descargan todos a la vez en la carpeta en la que tengas el ejecutable wget.exe (en mi caso en el disco local), de hecho el comando sería:

C:\wget>wget https://ozonewatch.gsfc.nasa.gov/data/omi/Y2010/ -r -l 1

A mí me funcionó eso.

Obviamente sirve para descargar más tipos de archivos, no solo txt.